# Web crawler encounter javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-crawler

I'm new to web crawling. I am trying to crawl a webpage using java and I encounter a problem. I need to get the link in a 'HTML  Tag' whose href is a javascript function. I have no idea how to get the link in the javascript function. Here is the html source and javascript source.

HTML

```
<a href='javascript:ShowPostGridUnique(205316,0);'>link</a>
```

JS`ShowPostGridUnique`

```
function ShowPostGridUnique(parentpostid, pageShow) {
    //alert(parentpostid);
    var divid;
    divid = 'divPostContent' + parentpostid;
    if (document.getElementById(divid).className == 'divGridShow') {
        document.getElementById(divid).className = 'divGridHide';
        document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(divid).className = 'divGridShow';
        // call server side method
        PageMethods.divParentInnerHtml( parentpostid, pageShow, CallSuccessShowPost, CallFailedAlert, parentpostid);
        try {
            divid = 'TDtitle' + parentpostid;
            document.getElementById(divid).className = 'TDtitle';
            divid = 'TDPage' + parentpostid;
            document.getElementById(divid).className = 'TDtitle';
        }
        catch (err) {
            //Handle errors here
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get the link of href? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Headless Browser like Phantomjs.
   http://phantomjs.org/
2. Use ghostdriver/selenium to control Phantomjs
   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium
   https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use Java